# Contractibility of complex manifold

Tags: general-topology

I'm trying to show that for $v^2 = w^4 - a^4$  for real $a$ and complex $v, w$ that this manifold deform retracts to a point $(0, a)$ but can't seem to figure out a path that remains on the surface.  Is this actually contractible?